# Format number to have double digit in xsl?

Tags: xslt, format, xls

I have a XSL file when it translates a number. It comes out as 1.9 but I want it to come as 1.90. I just want to format it so it comes out with an additional 0.

```
<BobPrice>
    <xsl:value-of select="PriceUnit"/
</BobPrice>
```

So the above XSL. I want to change this tag so a number like 0.9. Should come out as 0.90.

Answer (score 1):

The [`format-number()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#format-number) function does that:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(PriceUnit, '0.00')"/>
```